# How to add backdrop image?

Tags: rendering, mesh, texturing, materials, uv

How do I add backdrop images like this one and see it in the render, too?
The one in the picture I added by Shift+A-->Empty-->Image...

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Use the "add images as planes" facility.

Comment: Already tried but it doesn't show me the image!

Comment: nvm it works! I wasn't in Render Mode! Thanks